# How to record video in One to one video call using kurento?

Tags: node.js, video, kurento

I've seen the kurento tutorial of [one to one video call](http://www.kurento.org/docs/6.1.0/tutorials/node/tutorial-4-one2one.html) and I made some changes to record the caller for testing .
you can say the first step to record caller and callee . but it seems that doesn't work with me .

I'm a beginner in  nodejs and web-rtc but applied some things on kurento guided by the hello and the one to one tutorials .
and thanks for your help. 
my code  [here](https://github.com/abdullahalnahhal/Making-record-On-One-2-One-example/blob/master/server.js)

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything with the recorder. Actually, I think you should be getting errors because

- You are creating the recorder [here](https://github.com/abdullahalnahhal/Making-record-On-One-2-One-example/blob/master/server.js#L122)
- You are later using it [here](https://github.com/abdullahalnahhal/Making-record-On-One-2-One-example/blob/master/server.js#L178)

If I got the scopes right, the `recorderEnpoint` created is in an scope that is not reachable from the piece of code that uses that endpoint later. I guess you are getting an exception somewhere in your server.

Comment: first thank you , second I'm sorry for being late in my comment , then I did what You've tolled to me but it still not working .
I've made changes In the same link in the top .
And thank you very much .

Comment: [This](https://github.com/abdullahalnahhal/Making-record-On-One-2-One-example/blob/master/server.js#L178) has to go inside [this](https://github.com/abdullahalnahhal/Making-record-On-One-2-One-example/blob/master/server.js#L176) callback, after the error check. This is not an issue with Kurento, but with Javascript scopes. I'd suggest you take some time understanding scopes on Javascript, as it will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: @AbdullahAl_Nahhal any progress with this?